# How can we convert Prefix to Postfix expression ( without using expression tree)?

Tags: stack, expression-trees, prefix, postfix-notation

By using Stack data structure, we can easily convert "Infix to Postfix" and "infix to Prefix" but I can't convert Prefix to postfix.

yes, we can convert prefix to infix then infix to postfix. but I want direct conversion from prefix to postfix.

Is there any feasible solution (not expression tree) ?

Comment: This question is not home work and I am not a School Boy or College guy. 
Jonathan, why you asking like this " Is this a homework problem? "

Comment: because it sounds like a homework problem. And the answer is usually chapter 1 in any compiler book.